# Update pannel not working with jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net

HI.

I am using JQuery tabs in my aspx page, but update panel is not working. If I do any operation in tab2, after posting back, tab1 is activated. How can i solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problems exist while using client side scripts and asp:update panel.So u just add all your scripts from server side

For eg:(at ServerSide)

```
   private void addScript()
        {
            string script = @"<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">
              $(document).ready(function() {
                // functions 
   </script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "validation", script, false);
        }
```

The above one is a server side script and here we are adding to StartupScript.Call this function on Page_Load().I hope this will works for you.You can also remove all your client side script from *.aspx page and add it to the function.